# limit of recursive function

Tags: limits

I've been struggling with this for a while now and can't seem to get it right.
Let $f(x)= \frac{x^2+3}{2x}$ from $0 $ to $\infty $. Show that $0\lt x \lt \sqrt{3}$ implies $\sqrt{3} \lt f(x)$ 
and show if we define $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ then 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n =\sqrt{3}$$ when $x_0 \gt 0$
It's easy to check that $f(\sqrt{3}) = \sqrt{3}$ but limits is not one of my strong points. I've also shown that $f(x) < 3/x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)-\sqrt{3} = {(x-\sqrt{3})^2 \over 2x} \ge 0$. So we have $x_k \ge \sqrt{3}$ for $k \ge 1$.

Since $f(x)-\sqrt{3} = {x-\sqrt{3} \over 2x} (x-\sqrt{3})$, this suggests that we look at $\phi(x) = {x-\sqrt{3} \over 2x}$. It is straightforward to show that $\phi$ is strictly increasing for $x >0$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(x) = {1 \over 2}$. Furthermore, $\phi(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge \sqrt{3}$.

Hence we have $f(x) -\sqrt{3} \le {1 \over 2} (x-\sqrt{3})$ for $x \ge \sqrt{3}$.

In particular, this gives $0 \le x_{n+1}-\sqrt{3} \le {1 \over 2} (x_n-\sqrt{3})$ for $n \ge 1$ and so
$x_n-\sqrt{3} \le {1 \over 2^{k-1}} (x_1-\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: One question: everything makes sense but the last sentence. Could you please elaborate? Where did $\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ come from? Also does this prove that the limit is $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: If you have $0 \le t_{n+1} \le {1 \over 2} t_n$, then you have $0 \le t_n \le {1 \over 2^n} t_0$. Use induction if you want. This shows that $t_n \to 0$ which gives the desired result.

Comment: So if understood correctly, $ 0 \leq x_{n+1} - \sqrt{3}\leq \frac{1}{2} (x_n-\sqrt{3})$ tells us that $t_{n+1} = x_{n+1} - \sqrt{3}$ gets squeezed between $0$ and $t_n$ with $t_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Correct, well, I would say that $t_n = x_n-\sqrt{3}$ is squeezed between 0 and ${1 \over 2^n} t_0$ which goes to zero.

Comment: could you please show or point to a page where your first comment is explained. Having trouble proving it.

Comment: We have $t_1 \le {1 \over 2} t_0$. Suppose $t_n \le {1 \over 2^n} t_0$. Then $t_{n+1} \le {1 \over 2} t_n \le {1 \over 2} {1 \over 2^n} t_0 = {1 \over 2^{n+1}} t_0$, and hence the statement holds for all $n$.